# Refresh QuickBadge/ ImageView on a Fragment after taking a picture

Tags: android, image, imageview, fragment, android-camera

I want to take a picture in my App, so if I click on my `ImageView`/`QuickBagde` on my `Fragment`.

I'm able to take a picture, after that, I crop it and it return to my App. This is not a big deal and it's working well.

But how can I refresh the `ImageView`/`QuickBadge` to show up the taken picture?

I tried with:

```
    //get the returned data
    Bitmap thePic = data.getExtras().getParcelable("data");
    profilePic.setImageBitmap(thePic);
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Do you know the exact path of the image after you have cropped it?

Comment: Yes it do cause I tell the App where to save it

Comment: Save that path in a field variable then and after cropping `Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePathField);` then set that bitmap to your imageView and it will automatically invalidate with the new image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this

```
        Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagepath);
        imageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```